# DynamoDB mapper.batchLoad nullPointerException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm getting a nullPointerException in DynamoDB mapper.batchLoad. This is the code:

```
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDB);
    ArrayList<Object> itemsToGet = new ArrayList<>();

    Post post = new Post();
    post.setCode("001");
    post.setNick("myNick");
    itemsToGet.add(post);

    Map<String, List<Object>> items = mapper.batchLoad(itemsToGet);
```

And return this error:

```
06-04 16:32:20.108 11533-11576/com.resurgence.photofusion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
                                                                        Process: com.resurgence.photofusion, PID: 11533
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchGetItemResult com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB.batchGetItem(com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchGetItemRequest)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.processBatchGetRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:1870)
                                                                            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(DynamoDBMapper.java:1781)
                                                                            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(DynamoDBMapper.java:1835)
                                                                            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(DynamoDBMapper.java:1801)
                                                                            at com.resurgence.photofusion.database.PostsCrud.selectPostsByFeeds(PostsCrud.java:106)
                                                                            at com.resurgence.photofusion.activities.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:181)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

'Code' and 'Nick' are hashkey and rangekey of 'Posts' table and I'm trying to follow this example:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#d0e32065

I'm using batchLoad incorrectly? Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the complete stack trace?

Comment: Thanks Shibashis. I edited the question.

Comment: Can you check the annotation on the Post class, are they correctly annotated?

Comment: I think so. I performed some "mapper.save" by using the Posts class, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Can you confirm whether mapper.load works? Retrieve just one item

Comment: Thank you, Shibashis! Your tip was essential to solve the problem. The error was in the class that started the DynamoDB, which had been altered in recent days. After your tip (and cooler head), I checked the other classes of discovered this problem system: the Context sent to the mapper class was null. Thank you so much!

Comment: awesome, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you initialize dynamoDB, but the stacktrace shows dynamoDB is null. Would you please double check dynamoDB is correctly initialized?

Comment: Yes, Yangfan, the Context sent to mapper class was null. Problem solved. Thank you!